# Find top n elements in pandas dataframe column by keeping the grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, grouping

I am trying to find the top 5 elements of the column `total_petitions`, but keeping the ordered grouping I did.

```
df = df[['fy', 'EmployerState', 'total_petitions']]
table = df.groupby(['fy','EmployerState']).mean()
table.nlargest(5, 'total_petitions')
```

sample output:

```
        
fy  EmployerState   total_petitions
2020    WA           7039.333333
2016    MD           2647.400000
2017    MD           2313.142857
...     TX           2305.541667
2020    TX           2081.952381
```

desired output:

```
fy  EmployerState total_petitions   
2016    AL  3.875000
        AR  225.333333
        AZ  26.666667
        CA  326.056604
        CO  21.333333
... ... ...
2020    VA  36.714286
        WA  7039.333333
        WI  43.750000
        WV  8986086.08
        WY  1.000000
```

with the elements of `total_petitions` being the 5 states with highest means by year

Comment: `table = df.groupby(['fy','EmployerState']).mean().groupby('fy').nlargest(5)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang, when I run this, the error message is as follows: ```DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nlargest' ```

Comment: `table = df.groupby(['fy','EmployerState'])['total_petitions'].mean()...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is a pivot table:

```
df = df.pivot_table(values='total_petitions', index=['fy','EmployerState'])
df = df.groupby(level='fy')['total_petitions'].nlargest(5).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
```

Comment: I get the following error: ```ValueError: No group keys passed!```

Comment: Ok, try it with the edit I made.  Otherwise send me the data.

Comment: Still does not work, I get this error: ```DataError: No numeric types to aggregate```

Comment: How about that?

Comment: You're welcome.  Will you kindly choose it as your answer, instead of just "upvoting" it.